# equal width discretization and categorization for an attribute in my data frame with continuous data type

Tags: r, discretization

One attribute in my data frame has continuous data type (aggregatedInocme), I would like to create a new attribute with (Low, Mid, high) categories based on the value in the (aggregatedInocme) attribute. I have divided the categorizes into three ranges as appears in my code below

I have made a simple code using for loop and if statment to chaeck if the value of each cell in the attribute belongs to particular range then asign the corresponding string to it

```
y<-min(data_loanapp$aggregatedInocme)-0
x<-max(data_loanapp$aggregatedInocme)-min(data_loanapp$aggregatedInocme)
c1<-(y+(x/3))
c2<- (y+((2*x)/3))
rr <- c()
 for (val in data_loanapp$aggregatedInocme){
   if(val<= c1) {
      rr[val]<- append(rr[val], 'Low')
     }else if (c1< val<= c2){
      rr[val]<-append(rr[val], "mid")
     }else
      rr[val]<-append(rr[val], "high")
}

rr
```

I am expecting to have an attribute with either value of (Low, High, Mid). But I keep getting an attribute with all NA and and error 
Warning message:
In rr[val] <- append(rr[val], "high") :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

> }
>   Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
#this was used only to find the bins width
library(classInt)
classIntervals(data_loanapp$aggregatedInocme, 3)
data_loanapp$Cat_AggInc<- classIntervals(data_loanapp$aggregatedInocme, 3, 
style 
= 'equal')
#here i defined and created the categores 
data_loanapp$Income_Cat<-c( "low", "medium", "high")[
               findInterval(data_loanapp$aggregatedInocme, c(1442,4583, 6588, 81000))]
data_loanapp$Income_Cat
```